# Problem building a Qt5 project with QWebKit

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, qt5

I'm trying to port a simple project from Qt4 to Qt5. The project uses QWebKit. I installed the `qt5-default` and `libqt5webkit5-dev` packages. I then changed the qmake project file to contain this:

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

But then when I try to run `qmake`, I get this output:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick location sensors
```

I checked, and the `libqt5quick5`, `libqt5location5` and `libqt5sensors5` packages are all installed (they seems to be dependencies of `libqt5webkit`).

What am I missing?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, 64bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to install bunch of additional packages:

```
sudo apt-get install qtquick1-5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtsensors5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev
```

Not sure why they were not installed automatically. Perhaps the dependencies are not set right?